# The ng-click of angular js is not working

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-ng-click

ng-click not calling a function in the controller 
can anybody help me out with these?

```
<div class="buttonpanel" id ="btn-panel">
    <div class="btn blue" ng-Click='send_data()'><a>Save</a> </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please add a Plunkr or JSFiddle. Your HTML seems fine.

Comment: It would also help to actually see your controller. On first glance: maybe make the c lowerCase as in `ng-click`?

Comment: @muenchdo Tag `a` is missing some attributes. But thats not the error. Please post your controller.

Comment: @lin Single quotes are perfectly fine in HTML, check the [specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.2.2).

Answer (score -1):

Rajeshwar,

I'll rather make the inner div a button instead of embedding an anchor in a div.  The mark up does looks ok but I will not add an ng-click over over an anchor.

Try the below and see if it helps you:

```
<div class="buttonpanel" id="btn-panel">
    <button class="btn blue" ng-click='send_data()'>Save</button>      
</div>
```

SO1